# Primary ps4 and game sharing

Tags: ps4

My brother and I both own a ps4. His account is the primary account on his system, and my account is the primary on my system. If I log into his account on my ps4, can I play his games while I'm on my account WITHOUT making his account the primary on my ps4?

Answer (score 0):

You can only play his games while logged into his account anywhere, or on any account while on his primary PS4. To play his games on your PS4 you will need to be using his account, not your own.